# How far is transaction save effective?

Tags: collection, magento-1.8, model, performance

I have a requirement where I need to save multiple rows to a custom table at once.

so used

> CASE 1:

```
foreach($dataCollection as $data){
    $customModel->setData($data)
                 ->save();
    $customModel->unsetData();
}
```

but **this seemed to be a little inefficient way** as everytime the loop is executed, there was an insert query. Went through these questions:

- **[How to optimize saving multiple models?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14165850/how-to-optimize-saving-multiple-models)**
- **[Magento catching exceptions and rolling back database transactions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4878634/magento-catching-exceptions-and-rolling-back-database-transactions/4879133#4879133)**

> CASE 2:

```
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
foreach($dataCollection as $data){
     $customModel->setData($data)
     $transactionSave->addObject($customModel);
}
$transactionSave->save();
```

But this method seems to use the `save()` method inturn. So **this might be slower than the previous case**.

***So which is better case 1 or case 2?***

Answer (score 6):

The 2 methods are kind of the same thing. The `save`  method on `Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')` will loop through all the objects assigned to it and call `$object->save()`.
The only difference is that in the second case all the `save`s on the objects are done in the same transaction.
Do if one fails all the others that were previously saved will be rollback-ed.
And one "minor" change.
If you use this code for the second approach

```
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
foreach($dataCollection as $data){
     $customModel->setData($data);
     $transactionSave->addObject($customModel);
}
$transactionSave->save();
```

only one object will be saved. Since Objects are passed by reference you end up in `$transactionSave` with the same object.
When calling `$customModel->setData($data)` the second time, the data in the "previous" object will be overwritten.
You might want to do it this way:

```
$transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction');
foreach($dataCollection as $data){
     $customModel = Mage::getModel('../...');
     $customModel->setData($data);
     $transactionSave->addObject($customModel);
}
$transactionSave->save();
```